# Gradle script fails due to missing Android Emulator

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have created freestyle Jenkins project which supposed to run gradle script to build android artifacts and publishe it to some repostitories. It fails though. When I check logs error message says:

```
Failed to install the following SDK components:
  emulator Android Emulator
Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
```

Obviously I can not install Android Studio on Jenkins server. Have anyone encountered such a problem before and how can one fix this?

Comment: You don't need to install AndroidStudio, just an emulator https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line#tools-emulator

Comment: Have you checked the Android emulator plugin for Jenkins, this automates many android build related tasks including SDK installation  : https://plugins.jenkins.io/android-emulator/